# A better way to react to custom events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a self-contained jquery ui component and I want to give whomever uses the component a good amount of control. For instance, forms are an important part of my component, and my component has some built in form validation but I give the option for the user to disable the built-in validation. I want them to have the ability to do their own form validation on top of that.

So, when the form submission button is clicked, I fire a custom event and check a boolean.

```
this.element.trigger('customEvent');
if(canContinue) { ...
```

The boolean is true by default, but my thought is that the user could listen for my `customEvent` and then do their validation, and should the validation fail, switch the boolean to false so that the form won't submit.

This works.

However it feels hacked together, and I'm not sure if I'm doing this in a standard or acceptable way. Is there maybe something in Javascript or JQuery that I could better use to get this sort of logic to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is made easy using the triggerHandler method:

```
var handlerResult = this.element.triggerHandler("customEvent");
if (handlerResult || typeof handlerResult == "undefined") {
    alert("Success!");                           
}
```

All the user has to do to cancel is return false.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7B2Kw/1/

Comment: The problem is that if no one is listening for the customEvent, it's the same as returning false, which is not the functionality I want. This means I need to say  `if (this.element.triggerHandler('customEvent'))` and the user needs to return `false` to have it work, which is counter intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [Strategy](http://sokolmichael.com/posts/2013-03-08-strategy-design-pattern-in-javascript) design pattern, implement your validation as default strategy and let the user to implement custom strategies. User may configure your component with other validation strategy (e.g. pass it as one of the configuration properties or by setting relevant property of the component after it was instantiated). Below you can find an example:

```
$(function() {
    $.widget( "custom.mycomponent", {
        options: {
            validate: null
        },
        _validate: function() {
            return true;
        },
        _create: function() {
            this.options.validate = this.options.validate || this._validate;
            var that = this;
            this.element.on('keypress', function() {
                if(that.option('validate')()) {
                    this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                } else {                                        
                    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                }
            });
        },
        _setOptions: function() {
            this._superApply( arguments );
        },
        _setOption: function(key, value) {
            switch(key) {
                case 'validate': 
                    if(typeof value !== 'function') return;
            }
            this._super( key, value );
        }
    });

    // Instantiate with default options
    $('#my-component1').mycomponent();

    // Pass another validation strategy
    $('#my-component2').mycomponent({validate: function() {return false;}});

});
```

Working example in action http://jsbin.com/inavur/4/edit